# Feeding detection coordinates to an object tracker?

Tags: python, opencv, tensorflow, object-detection, object-detection-api

I'm working on multiple object tracking, I'm using the TensorFlow API to generate detections. I have managed to modify it a bit to make it return coordinates of the detected objects, now I want to feed the coordinates (bounding boxes) to an object tracker (CRST or KCF).
However running both detection and tracking simultaneously would be too computationally expensive. 
Is there any other methods to pass the coordinates or pause the detection?
Below is the detection code.
And in this link is the tracking code https://github.com/spmallick/learnopencv/blob/master/MultiObjectTracker/multiTracker.py

```
import numpy as np
import os
import six.moves.urllib as urllib
import sys
sys.path.insert(0,r'C:\Users\Ahmed.DESKTOP-KJ6U1BJ\.spyder-py3\TensorFlow\models\research\object_detection')
import tarfile
import tensorflow as tf
import zipfile
from collections import defaultdict
from io import StringIO
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image
import cv2
import imutils
from protos import string_int_label_map_pb2
from utils import visualization_utils2 as vis_util



def scale(bbox, width, height):
    x = int(bbox[0]*width)
    y = int(bbox[1]*height)
    w = int(bbox[2]*width)
    h = int(bbox[3]*height)
    return (x,y,w,h)

W = 800
H  = 600



videopath = "file:///C:/Users/Ahmed.DESKTOP-KJ6U1BJ/.spyder-py3/soccer4.mp4"
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(videopath)
# This is needed since the notebook is stored in the object_detection folder.
sys.path.append("..")
# # Model preparation 
# Any model exported using the `export_inference_graph.py` tool can be loaded here simply by changing `PATH_TO_CKPT` to point to a new .pb file.  
# By default we use an "SSD with Mobilenet" model here. See the [detection model zoo](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/detection_model_zoo.md) for a list of other models that can be run out-of-the-box with varying speeds and accuracies.

# What model to download.
MODEL_NAME = 'ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco_2017_11_17'
MODEL_FILE = MODEL_NAME + '.tar.gz'
DOWNLOAD_BASE = 'http://download.tensorflow.org/models/object_detection/'
# Path to frozen detection graph. This is the actual model that is used for the object detection.
PATH_TO_CKPT = MODEL_NAME + '/frozen_inference_graph.pb'
# List of the strings that is used to add correct label for each box.
PATH_TO_LABELS = r'C:\Users\Ahmed.DESKTOP-KJ6U1BJ\.spyder-py3\TensorFlow\models\research\object_detection\data\mscoco_label_map.pbtxt'
NUM_CLASSES = 90

# ## Download Model ( uncomment if the model isn't downloaded / comment if you alredy have the model)
"""
opener = urllib.request.URLopener()
opener.retrieve(DOWNLOAD_BASE + MODEL_FILE, MODEL_FILE)
tar_file = tarfile.open(MODEL_FILE)
for file in tar_file.getmembers():
  file_name = os.path.basename(file.name)
  if 'frozen_inference_graph.pb' in file_name:
    tar_file.extract(file, os.getcwd())
"""
# ## Load a (frozen) Tensorflow model into memory.

detection_graph = tf.Graph()
with detection_graph.as_default():
  od_graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
  with tf.gfile.GFile(PATH_TO_CKPT, 'rb') as fid:
    serialized_graph = fid.read()
    od_graph_def.ParseFromString(serialized_graph)
    tf.import_graph_def(od_graph_def, name='')

# ## Loading label map
# Label maps map indices to category names, so that when our convolution network predicts `5`, we know that this corresponds to `airplane`.  Here we use internal utility functions, but anything that returns a dictionary mapping integers to appropriate string labels would be fine

import label_map_util

label_map = label_map_util.load_labelmap(PATH_TO_LABELS)
categories = label_map_util.convert_label_map_to_categories(label_map, max_num_classes=NUM_CLASSES, use_display_name=True)
category_index = label_map_util.create_category_index(categories)

# # Detection


with detection_graph.as_default():
  with tf.Session(graph=detection_graph) as sess:
    while True :

      ret, image_np = cap.read()
      # Expand dimensions since the model expects images to have shape: [1, None, None, 3]
      image_np_expanded = np.expand_dims(image_np, axis=0)
      # Definite input and output Tensors for detection_graph
      image_tensor = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('image_tensor:0')
      # Each box represents a part of the image where a particular object was detected.
      detection_boxes = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_boxes:0')
      # Each score represent how level of confidence for each of the objects.
      # Score is shown on the result image, together with the class label.
      detection_scores = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_scores:0')
      detection_classes = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_classes:0')
      num_detections = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('num_detections:0')
      # Actual detection.
      (boxes, scores, classes, num) = sess.run(
          [detection_boxes, detection_scores, detection_classes, num_detections],
          feed_dict={image_tensor: image_np_expanded})
      # Visualization of the results of a detection.
      boxes2 = np.squeeze(boxes)
      max_boxes_to_draw =boxes2.shape[0]
      scores2 = np.squeeze(scores)
      min_score_thresh=0.7
      classes2 = np.squeeze(classes).astype(np.int32)
      for i in range(min(max_boxes_to_draw, boxes2.shape[0])):
        if boxes2 is None or scores2[i] > min_score_thresh:
          class_name = category_index[classes2[i]]['name']
          print ("This box is gonna get used", scale(boxes2[i], W ,  H),  class_name)

      cv2.imshow('Object Detection',cv2.resize(image_np,(800,600)))
      k = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xff
      if k == 27:
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        cap.release()    

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
cap.release
```

Comment: What have you tried ? Could you give some code to illustrate what you want to do ?

Comment: Please, be clearer. What do you mean by "pass the coordinates or pause the detection"?

Comment: The detection process is running , it's generating detections at every frame , if I simply create a new tracker for every detection , the window would just freeze due to the huge amount of calculations it has to perform.
That's why I thought if I can only run detection for the first frame only , or every set number of frames ( for exemple the detection runs once every 10 frames)

Answer (score 0):

you could count frames with a simple counter in the `while True` loop and "pause" the detection with an `if` statement before `session.run` like:

```
frame_count = 0
with detection_graph.as_default():
  with tf.Session(graph=detection_graph) as sess:
    while True :           
      ret, image_np = cap.read()
      #the first frame and every 10 frames do the detection
      if frame_count == 0:
         ###detection here
         #restart counter (from -10 to 0)
         frame_count = -10
      ##do tracking here
      frame_count += 1
```

This way the actual detection is done for the first frame and then every 10th frame, so in the other 9 frames you can do whatever you want.